# Unable to execute function manually via workbench in redshift DB

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

We have connected redshift DB in sql-workbench/aginity. I am able to create function but I couldn't EXECUTE that created function in workbench. Below is the sample syntax we tried to call the function.

```
execute public.test_function
execute test_function
```

By the way, is the correct syntax to execute a function?

Answer (score 1):

[As documented in the manual](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_EXECUTE.html) `execute` is used to run a *prepared statement* - not a function.

[To "execute" a function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-sql-udf.html#udf-scalar-sql-function-example), call it with a `select` statement:

```
select test_function();
```